# Does KEDA require Service, ServiceMonitor or Ingress?

Tags: kubernetes, keda

I am trying to implement Kubernetes Event Driven Autoscaling in a Spring Boot based application consuming messages from an ActiveMQ topic. I have defined a ScaledObject and have Prometheus set up. Does KEDA also require a Service and/or a ServiceMonitor object to be defined for KEDA to work, like it is for an HPA that scales a web service? Also, since this is a message queue consumer and not a web service, are there any reasons for needing an Ingress?